# Oracle Virtual box и вирусы

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Защитит ли virtual box систему в которой она запущена от вируса, если вирус заработает в вм?
Мне это нужно для того, чтобы проверить скачанные файлы на вирусы и не подцепить случайно их.

Comment: Если связи между основной системой и виртуальной системой нет никакой, то вирус точно не пройдет (отсутствие связи я подразумеваю как отсутствие общих папок, отсутствие локалки между системами и прочее)

Comment: Возможны как минимум два нехороших варианта при запуске такого кода под виртуальной машиной: 1. использование уязвимости виртуальной машины 2. определение работы под виртуальной машиной и отключение вредоносных функций (а при запуске на реальной машине все будет плохо). А чтобы просто проверить код на вирусы и совсем уж оградиться - проверьте онлайн.

Comment: @tilin пункт первый - фантастика. За 10 лет такого не встречал

Comment: Владимир, при наличии уязвимости в программном коде собственный опыт не обеспечивает надежность системы, вообще, никак. То бишь, это схоже с о словами: я вот уже 10 лет каждый день хожу под дряхлым обветшалым тополем, а он все на меня никак не падает и значит так будет дальше. На мой взгляд, это неправильное суждение. А уязвимости в разных версиях virtualbox однозначно были. Так что первый вариант не фантастика, эту уязвимость просто невыгодно эксплуатировать. Поэтому шансов нарваться мало. Но в случае направленной атаки могут воспользоваться ЛЮБЫМ слабым звеном.